# How do I make the text input box cursor blink automatically when the page loads?

Tags: javascript, html, css, autofocus

I want the cursor/line thing in the text box to automatically start blinking when the page loads. I've tried

```
contentEditable="true"
```

but that's not working

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to set focus on the text box.

This can be done either by

JavaScript `document.getElementById("fname").focus();`

or

Jquery `$( "#fname" ).focus();`

or

HTML5 `<input type="text" name="fname" autofocus />`

Comment: Yes. I listened to nice music on the way in; with some luck I will receive a brand new Mac Book Pro today ... and assuming I can motivate enough folks, there is that gold badge in some hours.

Comment: @LegendaryGoldCat *Legendary: Award Sept 7 '17* :-)

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5, you can simply use the input autofocus attribute.

However, beware that this does not work in some versions of IE.